# If $V$ is simple then is $V\otimes W$ is simple given $W$ is simple?

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $W$ be a simple, finite dimensional, $\mathbb{C}G$-module and $G$ is a finite group. Suppose $V$ is also a simple, finite dimensional, $\mathbb{C}G$-module, would it be the case that $V\otimes W$ be simple as well (again, as a $\mathbb{C}G$ module)?

[Apologies in advance if I am writing something totally non-sense, I am really new to these ideas and thus any criticism is really welcomed.]

I feel like the answer is yes. Since $W$ is simple, we have $W^*$ is simple (this is the dual of $W$). Thus we can consider if $V\otimes W^*$ is simple instead.

Recall that $V\otimes W^*\cong Hom(W,V)$ and since both $V$, $W$ are simple, $Hom(W,V)$ is either just identically $0$ or $W\cong V$ by simplicity, in the latter case $Hom(W,V)=\mathbb{C}$, by Schur's Lemma, which is simple again. Thus in either case $V\otimes W^*$ is simple.

I may just 'proved' something that is false as I really haven't got much clue about this.

I would really appreciate some feedbacks!

Comment: I think when you say Maschke's theorem you mean Schur's lemma.

Comment: One way to tell that this can't be true:  any finite group $G$ has finitely many irreducible $\mathbb C$-representations up to isomorphism, and if $G$ is nonabelian then some of these have dimension $> 1$.  If the tensor product of two simple $G$-modules were always simple, then you could use this to build irreducible representations of arbitrarily large dimension.

Comment: @RaviFernando Ahh right, thank you, that is a brilliant way to think about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schur's lemma says that the space of *$\mathbb{C}G$-linear* maps $W\to V$ is either trivial or $\mathbb{C}$.  But here $\operatorname{Hom}(W,V)$ is the space of all *$\mathbb{C}$-linear* maps $W\to V$, equipped with the natural action of $G$ induced by the action of $G$ on $W$ and $V$.  This is typically much larger than the $\mathbb{C}G$-linear maps, which are just the $G$-invariant elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(W,V)$.

In fact, this proves that $\operatorname{Hom}(W,V)$ is never simple if $W\cong V$ and they have dimension greater than $1$, since in that case the $G$-invariant elements form a $1$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $\operatorname{Hom}(W,V)$, and this is a proper submodule since $\operatorname{Hom}(W,V)$ has dimension $(\dim V)^2>1$.

Comment: Yes, at the very least, the original question's sense of tensor product needs to be clarified. Over _what_?